# FlexLayout Angular and align items in one line on start as well as on the end

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I use the Angular flexlayout library within angular 7/8. I want to have 4 buttons on the left side(flex-start) and I want to have the two checkboxes on the right side(flex-end) on the same level.
I want to do it within the flexlayout Angular library if this is possible.

I have tried the code I show you below. I have also tryed to make 2 mat-card-action components but then they are below each other and not in one line.

```html
<mat-card-actions fxLayoutGap="1em">

  <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="newRows()">Add</button>
  <button [disabled]="selectedRow != undefined && selectedRow.isBevoorschotting" mat-raised-button color="accent"
    (click)="updateRows()">Update</button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="deleteRows()" [disabled]='!isAdmin'>Delete</button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="refresh(0)">Refresh</button>

  <mat-checkbox (change)="onclickMutatieVelden()" [(ngModel)]="toonMutatievelden">
    <p>Mutatie velden aan...</p>
  </mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox (change)="onclickMaakInactief()" *ngIf="selectedRow" [(ngModel)]="!selectedRow.isActief">
    <p>Maak Inactief...</p>
  </mat-checkbox>
</mat-card-actions>

Anybody can help me out ?
```

Comment: The result at this moment is that all the buttons and the checkboxes are on the left side.

Comment: Instead of commenting your own question, try to add the relevant information in the question itself.

Comment: Yes Adriano, normally I do but in this case because it was a very smaal remark I added it as a comment, Next time I will use the edit. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could be like this?

```
<mat-card fxLayout="row">
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="50"     fxLayoutGap="5px">
      <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="newRows()">Add</button>
      <button [disabled]="selectedRow != undefined && selectedRow.isBevoorschotting" mat-raised-button color="accent"
        (click)="updateRows()">Update</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="deleteRows()" [disabled]='!isAdmin'>Delete</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="refresh(0)">Refresh</button>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout="row"  fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="end center">
      <mat-checkbox (change)="onclickMutatieVelden()" [(ngModel)]="toonMutatievelden">
        <p>Mutatie velden aan...</p>
      </mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="onclickMaakInactief()" *ngIf="selectedRow" [(ngModel)]="!selectedRow.isActief">
        <p>Maak Inactief...</p>
      </mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-gxew4y?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Would you be able to add some context to the changes you made to make it work?

Comment: Thanks Matias, this is helpfull. I tried to replace the div with a ng-container, but then it errors. It should be nice if I could replace the div with a ng-container or maybe some other Angular element. But maybe using Angular components like ng-container doesnt fit for this case ?

Comment: For some reason Angular Material and Angular flexLayout doesn't work for me. I don't know but  my components are jumping around on the screen, so I stop with  flexLayout for my project

Comment: The flex-layout directives are meant to work on actual HTML element containers, not ng-container, which gets removed during compilation.

Comment: @Matias Thanks, so conclusion is I need to use div's like in your solution.

Comment: Right! Since as the Angular documentation says "The Angular <ng-container> is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM".